# Deixar label lado a lado , bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Galera to com dificuldade em deixar as labels Nome e Assunto lado a lado , simplesmente não vai[image: código]

Comment: Tente postar o código em forma de texto para que possamos analisá-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Para vc colocar o `label` ao lado do `input` vc tem que usar a tag form dessa forma `<form class="form-horizontal">` esse é o modelo da documentação oficial.

Documentação do `.form-horizontal`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal

Veja o exemplo com o seu código usando o padrão oficial do BS3

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<footer>
        <div class="container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="contatos" style="margin-top: 60px">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>ENTRE EM CONTATO</h2>
            </div>
        
            <div class="row" id="infos">
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="formulario">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Nome: </label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu Nome">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Assunto: </label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assunto" placeholder="Digite o assunto">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Bruno!

Bom, eu vou tentar te explicar como funciona o GRID do Bootstrap:

Você declarou certo, porém cada col tem sua proporção, a sequência é assim;

- col-xs (Para celulares super pequenos ou extrasmall)
- col-sm (Para tablets pequenos ou small)
- col-md (Para desktops de tamanho médio ou medium)
- col-lg (Para desktops de tamanho grande ou large)

Tentei resumir para melhor compreensão, o que você pode fazer pra que a mesma coluna ser responsiva no mobile ou tablet, é mixar os tamanhos, por exemplo:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"> 
   conteúdo
</div>
```

Lógico que isso, conforme sua necessidade, o único problema é que você está unindo **col,row e container** tudo na mesma declaração, e isso é um por linha ,agora a estrutura ficaria assim:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h2>Entre em contato</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Nome
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Assunto
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- fim container-->
```

Agora você pode testar também **container-fluid**, abaixo segue o link da estrutura, acho bacana você dar uma lida :

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Espero ter te ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Para deixar o label do lado do input, você precisa colocar na sua tag `<form>` a seguinte `class`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
```

Mas essa explicação o [hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl) já lhe forneceu. Mas se seu objetivo é deixar um `input` do lado do outro, você precisa fazer alguns jogos de classes entre as suas `<div>`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<footer>
<div class="container-fluid" id="contatos" style="margin-top: 60px">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h2>ENTRE EM CONTATO</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="infos">
            <form>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Nome: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu Nome">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Assunto: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assunto" placeholder="Digite o assunto">
                   </div>
              </div>
          </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Selecione ver em "Página Toda" para visualizar o resultado.
>
> Aconselho você ler mais a documentação do bootstrap para aprender mais sobre as classes.

**[Documentação Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)**

Creio que isso irá ajudar.